# How to pass a parameter from blade template to controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, roots-sage

I'm working on a sage template on bedrock boilerplate,
which uses laravel blade and controller. I'm getting
posts data from WordPress API and displaying it by category.
This gets done on controller. I want to pass a parameter
on the blade template so controller knows which category
to retrieve. Here is the code.

```
public function getposts3($category = 2) {
        
        $args = array(
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'per_page' => 10,
            'categories' => $category,
            );
         
          $url = add_query_arg( $args, 'https://localhost/bedrock/web/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');
          
          $stuff = wp_remote_get($url, array('sslverify' => FALSE));
          
          $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($stuff);
          
          $posts = json_decode($body);

          return $posts;
    }
```

```
@foreach ($getposts3 as $post)
  <div class="w-1/2  bg-purple-light rounded m-auto mb-5">
    <h1>{{$post->title->rendered}}</h1>
    <div>{!!$post->content->rendered!!}</div>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

I come from JavaScript so I tried doing `$getposts3(3)`
to pass the parameter but it doesn't work. What is
the correct way to do this?

Also I want to put a button that will change the parameter
and it should call the function again and reload all the posts
from the new category. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a route for getposts3

```
function getposts3(Request $request) {
 // curl to wordpress api
 // you can get category id that client choosen from $request
 return response()->json($curlResponse);
}
```

Then from client side you have to make an api call to getposts3 and append it to html body

Comment: Maybe I didn't express well my intentions, category shouldn't be hard coded but rather dinamycally set every time I call the function. Is that possible?

Comment: Is it that category id has to be fetched from client side? I mean you have to load category items and display on website only after user clicks category button?

Comment: Yes that's right, should I change the posts so it´s easyer to understand?

Comment: Yep I got it, you want to use JavaScript to call api. I have edited my answer. If you didnot understand please poste your JavaScript also